# on what factors does the size of IPA depends?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store, ipa

I am working on an App, that includes iphone(4,5 potarit only) and Ipad(Landscape as well Potarit). **App includes 120 MB of IMAGES** and the folder size of my project is 123 MB.
But I made its ipa, that goes to **185 MB** . I am worried about the size of the build. How it happened to become 185 MB.

---

1. On what factors it is depending upon?
2. How Can I reduce the size of my build?
3. Will there be any problem uploading this app to the app store?

   **There are total of 15*3=45 NIB files in my project.**

Comment: My game is roughly 800MB. You shouldn't worry about the size.

Comment: A tool I found particularly useful for my images is http://imageoptim.com/ - I reduced my images' sizes by nearly 30-40% each.

Comment: @Omega games are something else, they can be of GB's too. Mine is an app(a pdf reading) with huge heavy images

Comment: Whether it is a game or a pdf reading program, they're both apps and go through the same process. My app is 800MB, so I don't think you should worry about your app size. It won't have problems with Apple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**part (3)** - "Will there be any problem uploading this app to the app store?"  :

The maximum size of .ipa in AppStore depends on your internet connection.

For app to be downloaded over 3G, the maximum size should be 100MB. Over Wi-fi connection or iTunes the maximum size is 2GB.

**part (2)**
To reduce the iPA size you can reduce the size of the images. Generally in an application you do not require high resolution images (not more than what the device supports).

If there are images you can make the application download from some external server, that would be better. That way you can download the images the first time app is launched and save in the sandbox of the app and they can be used later in the app by fetching from the sandbox. This can reduce your iPA size considerably.

**part(1)**
Generally the binary size is less than the actual folder size. I could not see from where your iPA size is increasing.

Comment: I would really appreciate if there is a comment after down vote. It makes me understand my flaw and correct it.

Comment: Your comment is right but I think you are not on the same page about question. He asked about factor of IPA size compression not the size that could be download.

Comment: The part 3 of his question says "Will there be any problem uploading this app to the app store?" I answered that part specifically. Let me edit my answer for more clarity

Comment: Sure but i think in general his problem is not uploading but the size of application

Comment: thanks evey one , all comments and answer are useful for me. Like using jpg instead png, will help a lot. but my images are 120 mb only and build is 185 mb. anyways i will rebuild my app with jpg and look the size then. and will be back here

Comment: While building the application for app store if debug symbols are included for symbolication for crashes in iTunes Connect, the size of the binary is more.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know

1 . ipa file size mostly depends on the Images size.

2 . So try to ask your designers to reduce the image for saving the memory or try to use the .jpg files for images except for splash screens,icons. No need to worry about the xib files .

3 . There is no need to worry about the size while releasing the app . Only issue is takes some time to download from the iTunes.

Comment: yes I am using the png Images, using Images.xcassets, I tried to put my jpg in Images.xcassets. But id didn't accept. Today After reading your post I tried Jpg images without using Images.xcassets, got success. Thank you for valuable suggestion. 
One more concern, Images were 120 MB and project size 123 mb, but the Build is 185 MB. any idea about the same?

Comment: Does the number of XIB files has to do any thing with this?

Comment: Nothing give much difference , the change could be in kbs

Comment: jpg was a good advice. Build size is reduce to 49.5 MB from to 185 MB.
But My client is still not happy, as his competitor's app is mere 8 MB only(a Magazine reading app). Is there any thing else I can do

Comment: check your project files i think some files are there which are not used in your project. delete them

Answer (score 1):

The size of application mostly not depend on the code but on the resources you have added into your application like images, video and sound files.

Most time number of images to support the different display need to add more images cause large size of IPA but for that I think the best way is use stretchable images that decrease IPA size around upto 40 to 60 percent and very neat and clean. do not include over side video and mp3 just compress them at optimum level so user experience will be great. Size could be around 40 mb is best for general ios application

Comment: i am using png images, i will make them to jpg now. It gonna reduce the size. and will get back to this post. Does the number of XIB files has to do any thing with this?

Comment: JPG is not a solution and its not supported and compress by pngcrush tool to optimize image and not give you that feel, go for optimize solution

Comment: Not much because they are just xml files so not a big concern for size

Comment: I was having a background image in PNG format of 2.8 mb, I converted it to jpg resulted in 300 kb. does pngcrush tool provide more efficient and optimize images?

Comment: for background you need only 10px image and set programatically and its going to repeat it self so you will save your size and its more optimize option then converting into jpg

Comment: For png images I've found that [TinyPNG](https://tinypng.com) is great! (Though I don't know if the pngoptimizer increases it's size again)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to download necessary assets during the first launch.

**Pro**: user will only get images that compatible with his device

**Con**: there must be a stable internet connection to download the images. Wi-Fi is preferred, because 3G is not always free of charge for user.